# JavaScript-Newbie is confused: if(event.shiftKey == 57)?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I hope I'm at the right place for this kind of question 
I just started learning programming with the Meta-Course on Coursera and after the JavaScript-Part I thought it would be a good idea to review other people's codes on GitHub to get some feeling and understanding for whole projects.

So now I'm sitting here, spent 2hrs on research and feeling stupid af...
I don't get this piece of code:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.shiftKey == 57) {
    event.key = "(";
```

afaik shiftKey always returns a boolean value - so how this one can work? (And yes it really does).
Can anyone explain that to me pls?

Tried to google it for over 2hrs now.

Comment: FWIW it would have been useful to cite the source where you got this code, so that we could see it in-context.  The code might work, but it does seem confusing af, which means that it is bad code by definition, no matter how clever it might be.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ChatGPT is right in some cases but could be horribly wrong sometimes... Shouldn't be the go-to solution to finding what a block of code does. I am 90% it would get it wrong for more complex code snippets. Throwing that out there, respectfully ofc.

Comment: You are correct that shiftKey always has a boolean value and this expression will thus always be false. Why do you believe that this code "works", have you tested it yourself? There is a lot of buggy code to be found on GitHub :p.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I'm new here as well  - here's the whole code: https://github.com/harsh98trivedi/Simple-JavaScript-Calculator/blob/master/calc.js

Comment: @I_throw_but_dont_catch: 1.   I use ChatGPT4, not its brain-dead cousin, and 2.  I review the answer to see if it makes sense to me before offering a link to anyone.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I understand *you* review the answer before posting it but the OP might not have as much experience with JS as you do... Going straight to ChatGPT should not be the go-to solution is all I'm saying. There are plenty of good books, online resources and so on

Comment: It would have been the same answer had I personally posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer: It doesn't work, it's a bug

Since, as you pointed out, shiftKey always returns a boolean value, the expression `(event.shiftKey == 57)` will always be false, looking at the code around it on [GitHub](https://github.com/harsh98trivedi/Simple-JavaScript-Calculator/blob/master/calc.js):

```js
if (event.shiftKey == 57) {
    event.key = "(";
} else if (event.shiftKey == 48) {
    event.key = ")";
} else if (event.shiftKey == 53) {
    event.key = "%";
}
```

We can see that the developer essentially tried to implement the shift key functionality himself. (Note that 57 is the ascii value of the `9` character and 48 of `0`, and `shift+0` == `)` on a US keyboard layout) **You don't have to implement shift key behavior manually**, the browser already takes care of it for you. In fact since different keyboard layouts put different shift key modifiers on different places I strongly suggest that you don't.

It's essentially just a bug, a pretty harmless one since the code is never triggered and nothing is lost here. You could easily imagine how a developer might mistakenly write this code and then test the shift key behavior and assume that since the shift key works his code must be working too.

I think this is a really good catch for a new developer though! If you're feeling up to it you could open an issue or a pull request ;).

Comment: Ohh okay great, thanks! But how does it still detect the right key in the webapp ( https://harsh98trivedi.github.io/Simple-JavaScript-Calculator/ )?

Comment: When you press the `0` key and shift at the same time the browser creates an event with `event.key === ')'`, so the code doesn't really detect anything, its just that the browser already implements the shift key by default.

Comment: ohhhh okay now I get it - I also didn't think about the fact that die US-Keyboard has ( & ) on 9 & 0 (in german its on 8 & 9)...ok now I get it I think - thank you! :D

Comment: Oh that's my bad, I assumed you had a US keyboard. Yeah shift+0 = `)` on a US layout, that's an important piece of context.

Answer (score 1):

So keys have [ascii values](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=adapters-ascii-decimal-hexadecimal-octal-binary-conversion-table) assigned to them and it looks as though this person wants to return a open bracket when someone hits the "9" key (ascii value 57) while pressing shift. What it seems is confusing you is [the difference between == and === in javascript][2], learning about [truthy and falsy][3] values will also probably help you understand what is going on here. However, without any context, I'm unsure this code will do what it intends to do, but I hope these resources will help you understand.

[2]: [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/loose-vs-strict-equality-in-javascript/#:~:text=The%20%3D%3D%20operator%20performs%20a,well%20as%20the%20same%20value](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/loose-vs-strict-equality-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=The%20%3D%3D%20operator%20performs%20a,well%20as%20the%20same%20value)).
[3]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).